# Build JSON response to Ajax call

Tags: java

I try to build a JSON response in my servlet.
The response should be somewhat like this:

```
{   
"firm1":["firm1project1","firm1project2","firm1project3"],
"firm2":["firm2project1","firm2project2","firm2project3"],
"firm3":["firm3project1","firm3project2","firm3project3"],
"firm4":["firm4project1","firm4project2","firm4project3"]
}
```

Here how I try to do so:
make a query to the database to determine how many "firms" do I have (these also will be keys of the JSON response):

```
while(result.next()){
    aFirms.add(result.getString("firm_id"));
    firmsCounter++;
}
```

Then (the query here is inner join of table `firms` and `projects` to get projects of the specified firm only):

```
ArrayList<String> aProjects = new ArrayList<String>();
while(i<firmsCounter){
    query="<query here>";
    result = statement.executeQuery(query);
    while(result.next()){
        aProjects.add(result.getString("project_name"));
    }
    jsonOutputObject.put(aFirms.get(i), aProjects);
    i++;
    aProjects.clear();
}
```

This way I get keys and empty arrays. And if I comment `aProjects.clear();`, I get full arrays (all projects) in every `firm` key.

How do I solve this?

Thank you.

### EDIT:

Here is output part:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String json = new Gson().toJson(jsonOutputObject);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
out.write(json);
```

Here is the query I use:

```
query="select"+ 
    " PROJECT_NAME"+
    " from PROJECTS"+ 
    " inner join FIRMS"+ 
    " on FIRMS.FIRM_ID=PROJECTS.FIRM_ID"+
    " where FIRMS.FIRM_ID="+"'"+aFirms.get(i)+"'";
```

Comment: What JSON Writer do you use? Or did you harcode it? Can you provide a bit more information?

Comment: what is the current query you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
I have changed the line:

```
jsonOutputObject.put(aFirms.get(i), aProjects);
```

to:

```
jsonOutputObject.put(aFirms.get(i), aProjects.toArray());
```

and left the line:

```
aProjects.clear();
```

uncommented.

This solution works fine.